# Jquery and the :active selector

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

This is my code:

```
$('#ss a:active').parent().addClass('ss-active');
```

I guess you can tell from my code what I want to do, but it's not working, how can I do this? and I also want when the user removes the mouse from the button to come back to normal state, what I mean by: "the user removes the mouse from the button" is that the user can only hold click on the button for a while and it should see the`:active` statement.

I can't do this with css because I need the parent of that `<a>`.

//Here it is, how I got it working!

```
    $('#solicita a').mousedown(function() {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('solicita-hover'))
    {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('solicita-hover');
        $(this).parent().addClass('solicita-active');
    }
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('solicita-active');
});
```

Comment: You should mark twerq's solution as the answer to your question

Answer (score 3):

Try using the mousedown() event:

```
$('#ss a').mousedown(function() {
 $(this).parent().addClass('ss-active');
}).mouseup(function() {
 $(this).parent().removeClass('ss-active');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

## An elaborated the answer for those new to jQuery

You should have some understanding of the order in which things happen in Javascript. When the browser sees the script you wrote, it parses it one line at a time from top to bottom (for the most part).

So, when it is reading your CSS ([Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/)) selectors in jQuery, it is going to look at the document *in its current state* for the selector you specified. This means that if you write `$('#my-id div').addClass( 'some-class' )` it will look for divs within the element whose id is `my-id` *at that particular moment* and add classes to them.

If you add more divs to `#my-id`, they **will not receive any extra classes** because they were not there when the browser originally read that line of Javascript.

So in the original question, when the asker writes `$('#ss a:active').parent().addClass('ss-active');`, the browser is only looking for `#ss a:active` at the millisecond that it reads that line.

**So, we have to bind Javascript events in order to detect something that might happen in the future**

This is why we end up having to do something like `$('#ss a').mousedown( function ).mouseup( function )`. Because this tells jQuery and the browser that you are waiting (or *[listening](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)*) for an event to occur.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery the ":" is a what they call a meta-character. What follows the ":" is usually jQuery selector syntax, like ":file" or ":has()".

":active" is a CSS pseudo-class so the use of ":" to denote pseudo-class is conflicting with jQuery selector syntax requirements.

All that said, you might try escaping the ":" with two backslashes as suggested in the jQuery api. I've not tried that, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually listen for selector rule matches in decent browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE10+), by setting a dummy CSS Keyframe and listening for the animationstart event to bubble up when it matches the selector you're listening for. Here's a blog post that dives into the guts of it and provides a tiny document/element extension, addSelectorListener, to make it easier to use: http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/08/06/css-selector-listeners/